# What is the differency between Messenger service and Data service in wpf mvvmlight

Tags: wpf, mvvm, mvvm-light, messenger, dataservice

I am trying to understand MvvmLight framework for Wpf. At the first look the **messenger service** and **data service** appear to do the same. They can both be used send data from ViewModel to the View. Is there anything more to this?

Please help.

Comment: If you are trying to learn the MVVM-Light framework: there is a great online course from the developer himself at [pluralsight.com](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses/TableOfContents/mvvm-light-toolkit-fundamentals). It's not free though...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A Data service is used to get data from the model (or back end server). The Messenger is a component that is used in order to allow the components (mostly view models but not only) to pass messages between them in a loosely coupled way.

details:
In MVVM, view models are usually not supposed to "know" each other. So when view model A wants to respond to things that happen in another view model B, it is not a good practice to for A to obtain a reference of B and attach an event handler. The messenger allows A to simply register to messages of a specific type, and for B to send this messages without any of them having a reference of each other. They only need to both "know" the message type.

Data Service is a component that is used to obtain data from the back end. View models refer to it and request data.

Hope this helps